# How do you set the text from an input to another element after clicking submit?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

For example when somebody inputs text and presses submit I want the text to be displayed in an h1 tag.

```
 <div>
   <label for="message"> Message:</label>

  <input type="text" id="message" name="message" class="m3">

  <button id="btn1" class="butt">Ready to Send?</button>

  <h1 id="test">Header</h1>    
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('btn1').click(function() {
    $('#test').text($("#message").val());
  });
});
```

Comment: You have missed `#` in `$('btn1')`

Comment: When you're submitting a form, a new page is loaded, there's no use to change the old page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn1').click(function() {
    $('#test').text($("#message").val());
//--> if you want to remove the value of the input after parsing the code, simply check if 
//--> not `null` or not `undefined` by placing the selector.val() in your if conditional... 
    if($("#message").val()){
      $("#message").val('');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="message"> Message:</label>

  <input type="text" id="message" name="message" class="m3">

  <button id="btn1" class="butt">Ready to Send?</button>

  <h1 id="test">Header</h1>
</div>
```

You did not add the `#` selector in JQuery for ID

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn1').click(function() {//<-- Make sure to add the ID selector # in Jquery
    $('#test').text($("#message").val());
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you know how then you'd be able to simultaneously make the text in the input disappear?

Comment: Sure check out my edit to the answer... Just check if set by placing the selector and its value `.val()` in the conditional, if it is set, then set the value to empty using two empty parentheses inside `val('')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn1').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#test').html($("#message").val());
    });
});
```

This would work fine, but like @Teemu says this removes the form functionality. If you want to add a check mechanism you can use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#message").keyup(function() {
        $("#test").html($("#message").val());
    });
});
```